# Add a text label to a polygon in google maps for iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, ios9

How do I add a text label on a polygon in Google Maps in iOS ?  I tried to add an overlay but it will only accept images not text? I am using google maps for ios with Swift on iOS 9.

This is the portion of code troubling me :

```
func updateUIMap(){

            var str = "Hello"
            var data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
            var drawText = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let size = CGSize(width: 24.0,height: 24.0)

           var inImage = UIImage()
            var textColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            var textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
            let textFontAttributes = [
                NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
            ]

            inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))

            var rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(24, 24, size.width, size.height)

            drawText.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

            var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()


            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            var overlay = GMSGroundOverlay(position: myposition, icon: newImage, zoomLevel:20)
            overlay.bearing = 0
            overlay.map = self.mapView
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code about adding an overlay to a polygon?

Comment: Just posted the code you requested!

Comment: [displayLayer()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CALayerDelegate_protocol/) is a delegate method from CALayerDelegate, so you need to implement this method, you can not directly call it from `GMSPolygon` which is a `NSObject`, if you want to display a text, you can convert a text to `UIImage` first.

Comment: I tried the above code still nothing showing up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `UIGraphics` drawing method might not be correct, you can try the following code to make a new image from a text:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(40.712216,
            longitude: -74.22655, zoom: 10)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        addGroundOverlay(camera.target)
    }

    func newImage(text: String, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        let drawText = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let textFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 20)!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(),
        ]

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        drawText?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }

    func addGroundOverlay(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        let overlay = GMSGroundOverlay(position: position, icon: newImage("Hello StackOverflow", size: CGSizeMake(150.0, 150.0)), zoomLevel: 10)
        overlay.bearing = 0
        overlay.map = (self.view as! GMSMapView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried something similar on SWIFT 3 but unless all the code is on the UIViewController, the cpu seems to be used a lot. Would creating a Marker in another class, then adding the UIImage to it produce some strange loop?

Answer (score 5):

I've found personally that the easiest way to do this is by adding a `GMSMarker` with a `UILabel` as it's `iconView` property.

```
            let labelMarker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "Hello friends"
            label.sizeToFit()
            labelMarker.iconView = label
            labelMarker.map = mapView
```

This approach can run into performance issues if you're adding a TON of markers to the map, but it's very effective if you need to add some labels to a map.

Comment: This is the more simple solution and it is working like a charm. Thank you :)