# Adding title to the circle of the google map in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am new in iOS development.
I am drawing a circle on user location and I want to add the title to the circle.
 I am using following code

```
var cirlce: GMSCircle!

let myPlacelatitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)! let myPlacelongitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!

let userLocation = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:  myPlacelatitude,
                                        longitude: myPlacelongitude,
                                        zoom: 7.5)
mapView.camera = userLocation

let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myPlacelatitude, myPlacelongitude)
marker.title = ""
marker.snippet = ""
marker.map = mapView

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: myPlacelatitude,
                                  longitude: myPlacelongitude, zoom: 6)

cirlce = GMSCircle(position: camera.target, radius: 50000)
cirlce.fillColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
cirlce1.isTappable = true
// the title is not setting to the circle in google map  
cirlce.title = "40 KM"
cirlce.map = mapView
```

Comment: There is a similar question, maybe it helps? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505355/add-a-text-label-to-a-polygon-in-google-maps-for-ios-swift

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_overlay#a04f4c8cc1cbf24ff6a354820049ca604) regarding GMSCircle states that some overlays, such as markers, will display the title on the map. I am not sure if this also holds true when using GMSCircle.

However as a workaround for your issue, you can put label in the GMSCircle when using GMSMarker with UIlabel from the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52028368/11025839) in the comment of Mamaessen above. Here is the code snippet incorporated in GMSCircle:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
    var circle: GMSCircle!

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 9.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        view = mapView
        circle = GMSCircle(position:camera.target , radius: 50000)
        circle.fillColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        circle.strokeColor = .blue
        circle.strokeWidth = 2
        circle.title = "THIS IS CIRCLE"
        circle.map = mapView

        let labelMarker = GMSMarker(position: camera.target)
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = circle.title
        label.textColor = UIColor.red
        label.sizeToFit()
        labelMarker.iconView = label
        labelMarker.map = mapView
      }

    }
```

If you want it to show after you tap the circle just like a popup when the circle is clicked, you can use an image which is a circle and use this as an icon to your marker and your text label should be in the marker title. The following is how I implement it in the code. Just a note you can notice the line `marker.icon = UIImage(named: "circle")`, this is where you put the name of the image that you want as your marker. In my case I made a *New Image Set* in my **Assets** and put the image I want to use as my custom marker.

```
lass ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 9.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        view = mapView

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "circle")
        marker.map = mapView
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps!